# Mapnik installation error on openSUSE 12.3

Tags: c++11, g++, installation, opensuse, mapnik

When trying to install mapnik on openSuse 12.3, ./configure command throws this error:
Checking if compiler (g++) supports -std=c++11 flag... (cached) no
C++ compiler does not support C++11 standard, which is required. Please use Mapnik 2.x instead of 3.x as an alternative

```
# more /proc/version
Linux version 3.7.10-1.24-desktop (geeko@buildhost) (gcc version 4.7.2 20130108 [gcc-4_7-branch revision 195012] (SUSE Linux) ) #1 SMP PREEMPT Wed Oct 2 11:15:18 UTC 2013 (375b8b4)
```

All dependencies are installed.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem on Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: Not yet unfortunately :(